# Obtener numero de serie del disco solido en C++ SIN utilizar api windows

Tags: c++

quisiera saber como obtener el numero de serie del disco solido (el numero físico que no cambia y es único por disco) bajo C++. Trabajo bajo Windows 7 y seria genial que no usara api de windows ya que se puede "engañar" a Windows para que la api muestre otros valores. Obviamente es para amarrar un programa al disco. Gracias.

Comment: Que has investigado?

Comment: Utiliza los drivers del fabricante.

Comment: Para acceder al hardware vas a usar sí o sí la API de Windows, Windows es el SO y, como tal, es el encargado de proveer el acceso a todo el hardware del sistema. Como te comenta @PaperBirdMaster puedes usar los drivers del fabricante... pero  ten encuenta que esos drivers se cargan en el SO, y para que eso pueda pasar, deben ser compatibles con la API del SO, ya que es la propia API del SO la que manda

Comment: Entonces que me recomiendan?